# Set JFrame background transparent but show contents

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I'm looking for some solution to turn an opaque, null JFrame background to transparent (no Translucent) but showing swing components like buttons containers etc...
here a example.

Default JFrame

[image: http://i.picasion.com/resize80/5c005816e8bd52d0d3325551ef14b1b1.jpg]

Something like, HERE disable the background

[image: http://i.picasion.com/resize80/742f5a46663852643b8aef69436e6dba.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple two step process...

First, you need to make a transparent frame...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new TestPane());
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

For every component you want to be see through, you need to make sure that it's set to be transparent, for example...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        add(new JLabel("Product"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Company"), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JLabel("Phone"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JComboBox(), gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setOpaque(false);
        buttons.add(new JButton("Add"));
        buttons.add(new JButton("Update"));
        buttons.add(new JButton("Delete"));
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(buttons, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        JPanel filler = new JPanel();
        filler.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        add(filler, gbc);

        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Product", "Company", "Phone"}, 0))), gbc);

    }

}
```

[image: TransparentFrame]

And a runnable example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            add(new JLabel("Product"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Company"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JLabel("Phone"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JComboBox(), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.setOpaque(false);
            buttons.add(new JButton("Add"));
            buttons.add(new JButton("Update"));
            buttons.add(new JButton("Delete"));
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(buttons, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            JPanel filler = new JPanel();
            filler.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
            add(filler, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(new String[]{"Product", "Company", "Phone"}, 0))), gbc);

        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

This is also a great way take "fake" a translucent frame...

[image: Translucent Frame]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    //...

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(getBackground());
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, i found a simple method before you post your answer xd that just set undecurated and setBackground(0,0,0,0) and set no opaque Panel... but thanks anyway :P